# commutative operators in a template class with an invariant return type

Tags: c++, templates

I have a fairly simple template class as follows. It is essentially an extension on the std::shared_ptr in C++11 where I would like to overload various operators. For this question the multiplication operator*(), and I would like it to be commutative.

```
template<typename T>
class PoolVar {
private:
   T * Variable;
public:
   T GetValue() const {
      assert(Variable != 0x0);
      return (*Variable);
   }
   template < typename U >
   friend T operator*(const PoolVar<T> & lhs, const PoolVar<U> & rhs) {
      return (lhs.GetValue() * rhs.GetValue());
   }
}
```

The issue with this implementation is when I utilize this PoolVar class with my Vector and Quaternion classes defined as follows. Both of which define the multiplication operator such that it is commutative to any user of the classes.

```
class Vector {
public:
   friend class Quaternion;
protected:
   double V_Value[3];
public:
   Vector operator*(const Quaternion & q) const;
}

class Quaternion {
public:
   friend class Vector;
protected:
   double Q_Scalar;
   Vector Q_Vector;
public:
   Vector operator*(const Vector & v) const;
}
```

What I want is for the PoolVar overloaded operator to essentially just be a pass through for any data type, such that I can do something like the following. Assume I allocated and initialized the Variable in the PoolVar objects correctly.

```
PoolVar<Vector> v;
PoolVar<Quaternion> q;
/* Stuff to create and initialize correctly. */
Vector v1 = v*q; // works currently
Vector v2 = q*v; // does not
Quaternion q1 = q*q; // ambiguous
```

The moment I attempt to add another friend operator as follows to PoolVar to achieve the pattern that does not work above, I get a bunch of error messages at compile time for ambiguous operators as marked above.

```
template < typename U >
friend T operator*(const PoolVar<U> & lhs, const PoolVar<T> & rhs) {
      return (lhs.GetValue() * rhs.GetValue());
}
```

The only thing I have found to work is to explicitly define the various combinations of the operators outside the PoolVar class, such as:

```
inline Vector operator*(PoolVar<Vector> & lhs, PoolVar<Quaternion> & rhs) {
   return (lhs.GetValue() * rhs.GetValue());
}
inline Vector operator*(PoolVar<Quaternion> & lhs, PoolVar<Vector> & rhs) {
   return (lhs.GetValue() * rhs.GetValue());
}
```

I really do not want to do this, if I can at all help it, because it is a serious limitation on the PoolVar class and would increase the maintenance of the code-base for any new special class like Vector and Quaternion.

The issue is not so much that I can create a commutative operator (I think) as it is that the return type for both definitions is the same (invariant), which leads to ambiguous overloading unless explicitly defined.

Is there any way to set up a template class to have commutative operators with invariant return types, such as this multiplication operator? Also, I should note that I do not have the luxury of utilizing C++11, if that perchance would have helped.

Comment: We're missing some lines from your template declarations.  Is `U` a type in your class template?

Comment: @JayMiller It is not. I am effectively using U to indicate any type not necessarily type T.

Comment: So `U` is a template argument to the operator* function not shown here?  If so that actually works in my testing.

Comment: That is to say it produces two different overloads, one in each template, and thus allows commutativity.

Comment: Shouldn't trailing return type feature solve this? I'm currently trying to put together an example but I am failing miserably:D

Comment: @JayMiller Your right, sorry I wasnt clear on what becomes ambiguous when I add the second friend operator. I edited the original post to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, since I haven't tried out all the new C++11 features but it seems like this could be solved with trailing return type thus allowing the compiler to deduce the return type. I put together an example from your snippets:

```
template<typename T>
class PoolVar {
private:
    T * Variable;
public:
    T GetValue() const {
        return (*Variable);
    }
    template <typename U>
    friend auto operator*(const PoolVar<T> & lhs, const PoolVar<U> & rhs) -> decltype(lhs * rhs) {
        return (lhs.GetValue() * rhs.GetValue());
    }
};

class Quaternion;

class Vector {
public:
    friend class Quaternion;
protected:
    double V_Value[3];
public:
    Vector operator*(const Quaternion & q) const;
};

class Quaternion {
public:
    friend class Vector;
protected:
    double Q_Scalar;
    Vector Q_Vector;
public:
    Vector operator*(const Vector & v) const;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    PoolVar<Vector> v;
    PoolVar<Quaternion> q;
    /* Stuff to create and initialize correctly. */
    Vector v1 = v*q;
    Vector v2 = q*v;
    return 0;
}
```

Since I'm on Windows and Visual Studio 2012 does not seem to support this I tried to compile it with gcc on Ubuntu VM and on http://gcc.godbolt.org/ but in both cases the compilers crash. Can anyone hint if this is an appropriate/inappropriate use of trailing return types in context of this question?

**EDIT**

I understood what was bad with the initial example, it introduces in infinitely deep recursion since the evaluation of the multiplication operator will yield evaluation of the same template. However when I tried:

```
    template <typename U>
    friend auto operator*(const PoolVar<T> & lhs, const PoolVar<U> & rhs) -> decltype(lhs.GetValue() * rhs.GetValue()) {
        return (lhs.GetValue() * rhs.GetValue());
    }
```

which gave errors about accessing incomplete type `PoolVar`, so I moved the operator outside of the class scope:

```
template<typename T>
class PoolVar {
private:
    T * Variable;
public:
    T GetValue() const {
        return (*Variable);
    }
};

template <typename T, typename U>
auto operator*(const PoolVar<T> & lhs, const PoolVar<U> & rhs) -> decltype(lhs.GetValue() * rhs.GetValue()) {
    return (lhs.GetValue() * rhs.GetValue());
}


class Quaternion;

class Vector {
public:
    friend class Quaternion;
protected:
    double V_Value[3];
public:
    Vector operator*(const Quaternion & q) const;
};

class Quaternion {
public:
    friend class Vector;
protected:
    double Q_Scalar;
    Vector Q_Vector;
public:
    Vector operator*(const Vector & v) const;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    PoolVar<Vector> v;
    PoolVar<Quaternion> q;
    /* Stuff to create and initialize correctly. */
    Vector v1 = v*q;
    Vector v2 = q*v;
    return 0;
}
```

This seemed to compile fine, so I guess my initial idea was right, thanks for the great question, so far I did not have a good example to try the trailing return types on.

**EDIT 2**

GCC has a built in extension called `typeof` that can solve this without C++11, but then again it is GCC specific:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class EvaluateResult
{
    static T m_a;
    static U m_b;
public:
    typedef typeof(m_a * m_b) Result;
};

template<typename T>
class PoolVar {
private:
    T * Variable;
public:
    T GetValue() const {
        return (*Variable);
    }
};

template <typename T, typename U>
typename EvaluateResult<T,U>::Result operator*(const PoolVar<T> & lhs, const PoolVar<U> & rhs) {
    return (lhs.GetValue() * rhs.GetValue());
}

class Quaternion;

class Vector {
public:
    friend class Quaternion;
protected:
    double V_Value[3];
public:
    Vector operator*(const Quaternion & q) const;
};

class Quaternion {
public:
    friend class Vector;
protected:
    double Q_Scalar;
    Vector Q_Vector;
public:
    Vector operator*(const Vector & v) const;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    PoolVar<Vector> v;
    PoolVar<Quaternion> q;
    /* Stuff to create and initialize correctly. */
    Vector v1 = v*q;
    Vector v2 = q*v;
}
```

Comment: I cannot utilize C++11 syntax unfortunately even if it does solve the problem.

Comment: @Dax, well anyway thanks for the question, at least for me it was valuable to understand how to solve this.

Comment: @Dax what GCC/ MS Visual Studio versions are you bound to? Maybe the solution can be achieved by using some pre C++11 compiler extensions like `typeof`.

Comment: gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55), which is ancient I know. Hopefully our systems will be moving to RHEL 6.5 in January 2015 where Ill get 4.4.7.

Comment: Do you know if typeof() requires RTTI?

Comment: @Dax https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html Well from this I get the notion that gcc 4.1.2 should support `typeof` and I dont think it requires RTTI since it is evaluated at compilation time not runtime.

Comment: Finally got around to testing out your Edit 2. It worked beautifully, quite ingenious. Thank you so much!

Comment: Side effect though, is that if a type does not define that operator then you are out of luck again. Example:

PoolVar.h: In instantiation of ‘PoolVar<double>::EvaluateResult<double, double>’:
error: invalid operands of types ‘double’ and ‘double’ to binary ‘operator%’

Comment: @Dax, well I don't think you can treat that as a side effect, since this effectively allows you to catch out invalid uses of the types. What behaivor would you expect for double and % since that is not implemented?

Comment: It isn't quite a "catch" since it doesn't compile even though I don't try to do a dould % double or a PoolVar<double> % PoolVar<double>. I was going to implement all the operators this way, until this snag caught me off guard. When I extended the class with all the operator types, it tried to make figure out all the types from those types. I guess I would rather it ignore them somehow.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't quite get it - can you add an example that triggers this error? I don't see how you can get it if you aren't invoking the % operator.

Comment: I figured out what I had to do. Initially I defined EvaluateResult with all the basic math operations return types:
`template<T, U> class EvaluateResult { static T lhs; static U rhs; typedef __typeof__(lhs * rhs) MulType; typedef __typeof__(lhs % rhs) ModType; }`

Comment: Continuation from above: I had the operators just like you defined them above. The problem was if I did a multiplication, the compiler would attempt to evaluate the `typedef __typeof__(lhs % rhs) ModType` also and generate code for that, which it couldn't when the types don't define that operator. Instead I had to create separate classes. for each operator.

Comment: @Dax, ah ok, got it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T>
class PoolVar {
private:
   T * Variable;
public:

   T GetValue() const {
      return (*Variable);
   }
   template < typename U >
   friend typename T::type operator*(const PoolVar<T> & lhs, const PoolVar<U> & rhs) {
      return (lhs.GetValue() * rhs.GetValue());
   }

// to handle equl types :)
   friend T operator*(const PoolVar<T> & lhs, const PoolVar<T> & rhs) {
      return (lhs.GetValue() * rhs.GetValue());
   }
};

class Vector {
public:
   friend class Quaternion;
protected:
   double V_Value[3];
public:
    Vector operator*(const Quaternion & q) const{ return Vector(); }
Vector operator*(const Vector & q) const{ return Vector(); }

    typedef Vector type;
};

class Quaternion {
public:
   friend class Vector;
protected:
   double Q_Scalar;
   Vector Q_Vector;
public:
    Vector operator*(const Vector & v) const {return Vector();};
Quaternion operator*(const Quaternion & v) const {return Quaternion();};

    typedef Vector type;
};


int main()
{
    PoolVar<Vector> v;
    PoolVar<Quaternion> q;


    Vector v1 = v * q; // good
    Vector v2 = q * v; // good

    Quaternion qq = q * q; // good
    Vector vv = v * v; // good

    return 0;
}
```

try this

Comment: This solution is less than ideal because it adds a requirement on to any type that ends up being utilized in the PoolVar class, which I want to minimize if not eliminate.